# Cannot install PC Tools firewall

Tags: firewall, uninstall

I am unable to install PC Tools firewall..It is fine up until after rebooting then the PcTools icon in the system tray hangs and indicates it is "initializing." I have waited 5 minutes and no change. I have tried multiple times.The Vista firewall was turned off prior to attempting to the attempted installation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is our customer service email: support@pctools.com. Give it a try so we can help directly or try our Twitter feed http://twitter.com/pctools. Let us know if you need more help! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you may want to clean the registry of PC Tools entries/files.I am sure some other readers on his site may know as they are for certain more knowledgeable than myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[AppRemover](http://www.appremover.com/)**.

[image]

> The free AppRemover utility enables
>   the thorough uninstallation of
>   security applications like antivirus
>   and antispyware from your computer.
>   Remove computer stress. Simply,
>   cleanly and effectively.